# Node-sass / sass-loader alternatives

Tags: python-2.x, node-sass, sass-loader

We are building a React app, with webpack, and I am using sass-loader which in turns it is using node-sass to convert SCSS into css.

The problem is that node-sass uses only python2.7, and I am working in a big company where they have extremely restricted policies on developer machines, where they allow only python3.x.

In order to install python2.7 I need to request an exception, which will goes to the company IT headquarter.

Is there an alternative for Node-sass that doesn't require python2.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node-sass does not require Python 2. Building native modules in Node.js does require Python 2 https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp.
node-sass ships prebuilt bindings for supported platforms https://github.com/sass/node-sass#supported-nodejs-versions-vary-by-release-please-consult-the-releases-page-below-is-a-quick-guide-for-minimium-support so you should only need Python to rebuild if your network blocks downloading those files from the GitHub releases or you're running old node-sass + new Node.js versions.

If that doesn't work for you, Dart-Sass can sometimes be used as an option in those tools https://github.com/sass/dart-sass

Comment: Your analysis is right.
My company prevents downloading binary files, and downloading the windows binding was failing, and this is why node-gyp was kicking to rebuild the module.

I will give dart-sass a try

Comment: Sorry, I know this answer is a few years old. But I'm wondering if can you explain this part of the sentence: "ships prebuilt bindings for supported platforms".
What are "prebuilt bindings"?

Thank you